# List properties of users using foreach comment

Tags: powershell

My goal is to list extended properties of a list of users by **Display Name or SamAccountName** pulling those names from a Csv. I am using the following script and it works but it either skips names in the Csv or repeats them. If I do one at a time it returns what I need but from the Csv it doesn’t. Csv has one column named `Name`.

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test.txt | Foreach {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Name)'" -Properties *
} | Select-Object DisplayName, SamAccountName, Title, Department, EmailAddress, ObjectGUID | Sort-Object Displayname | FT
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no users with the same `DisplayName` in AD ? Because this seems likely to be the problem

Comment: Could there be leading, or trailing spaces in your Names?

Comment: I checked and the names and they are clear of spaces, etc.

Comment: They are all unique names

Comment: Is your CSV a mix of `SamAccountName` and `DisplayName` or only contains `DisplayName` ?

Comment: Only display name

Comment: Smith, John and so on…

Comment: I found the problem and feel like a knucklehead. When I converted the orignial.txt to *.csv it put quotes around the "names" Everything is working fine now. Thanks all for the help folks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your current code, except for using `Import-Csv` on a `.txt` file (`test.txt`), I would assume this was a typo. I've added an `if` condition to help you troubleshoot so at least you would know which users where not found.

You should also avoid the use of `-Properties *`, querying all properties for the users is inefficient and slow.

```
$properties = @(
    'DisplayName'
    'SamAccountName'
    'Title'
    'Department'
    'EmailAddress'
    'ObjectGUID'
)

Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Name)'" -Properties $properties
    if(-not $adUser) {
        Write-Warning "'$($_.Name)' could not be found on AD"
        return # Go next
    }
    $adUser
} | Select-Object $properties | Sort-Object Displayname | Format-Table
```

Comment: Very nice I will give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: @D-a-n_L hope it helps you identify the problem, as for having duplicated users, the only possible reason for that would be if there are 2 or more users on AD with the same `DisplayName` __or__ you have duplicated users on your Csv.

Comment: I think there might be duplicates in AD for that matter; just as you mention. I can't see duplicates in the csv being an issue tho, unless there was a `-Unique` switch somewhere.